cannot get numpy to be detected when installing aeneas
On windows with python 3.13.1, when running pip install for something (aeneas) I cannot resolve: You must install numpy before installing aeneas
I've tried many different approaches, including following older stackoverflow posts on the matter.
I hoped this approach at least would work:
python -m venv myenv
.\myenv\Scripts\Activate
pip install numpy
pip list

Package Version
------- -------
numpy   2.2.1
pip     24.3.1

pip install aeneas

Collecting aeneas
  Using cached aeneas-1.7.3.0.tar.gz (5.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [3 lines of output]
      [ERRO] You must install numpy before installing aeneas
      [INFO] Try the following command:
      [INFO] $ sudo pip install numpy
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

pip install setuptools
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
pip install --no-build-isolation aeneas

...You must install numpy before installing aeneas


The error message is misleading, the problem is that numpy.distutils does not exist anymore and the package uses it for setup.

https://github.com/readbeyond/aeneas/issues/306 Found in https://github.com/readbeyond/aeneas/issues?q=is%3Aissue+distutils

The last two commands are right except that the package is old and requires numpy.distutils. That means it needs numpy version 1 and not 2. Also numpy.distutils was removed in python 3.12. So the solution is to use Python 3.11 and:
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel "numpy<2"
pip install --no-build-isolation aeneas


On windows I have better luck when running
python3 -m pip install

As it reduces potential path issues and ensures you're using the right pip for your python
Can you try that out?

This does not actually answer the question, should be a comment.
